# Cohomological dimension of a topological group with torsion

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, group-cohomology, classifying-spaces

I'm interested in a proof (or counter-example) of the following:

> Let $G$ be a topological group. If $G$ contains torsion then $H^n(BG)\neq 0$ for infinitely many $n$.

I know this is true for discrete groups, but I'm wondering if an analogous argument can be made for groups with a topology.

In the simplest case $G=C_k$ is cyclic of order $k<\infty$, and one computes $H^*(BC_k)\cong \mathbb{Z}[u]/(ku)$ for a class $u$ of degree $2$. The approach I know is to compute the Serre spectral sequence for the universal bundle $S^1 \to S^\infty \to \mathbb{C}P^\infty$, and notice that if we include $C_k \to S^1$ as the $k$-th roots of unity then $BC_k \simeq S^\infty/C_k$ and we get a fibre bundle $S^1/C_k \to BC_k \to \mathbb{C}P^\infty$ along with a map of fibrations from the universal bundle which is a map of degree $k$ in the fibres; now study the induced map on spectral sequences.

Now if $G$ is an arbitrary group with $k$-torsion, it has a subgroup isomorphic to $C_k$. If $G$ is discrete we can complete the argument using group cohomology $H^*_{Grp}(G)\cong H^*(BG)$, since in this context it's easy to see that $cd(G) \geq cd(C_k)=\infty$. However if $G$ is *not* discrete then group cohomology is more subtle (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72810/the-relationship-between-group-cohomology-and-topological-cohomology-theories)), because the usual definition computes $H^*(K(G,1))$ instead of $H^*(BG)$. Is there an analogous argument using an appropriate definition of $H^*_{TopGrp}(G)$?

Alternatively, is there an argument that avoids group cohomology altogether, and instead uses geometry (for Lie groups) or algebraic topology? I tried thinking about how the inclusion $C_k \to G$ induces a map on spectral sequences (like in the case $G=S^1$), but if $G$ is not connected then the coefficients are potentially twisted, and in either case there are too many unknowns for me to see what to do.

Comment: Probably you want to assume that $G$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: "cohomological degree" is usually known as "cohomological dimension", I guess.

Answer (score 1):

There's an argument involving the Euler characteristic that may or may not apply in your situation.  Namely, there's a fibration $$G \to EG \to BG$$ with $EG$ contractible.  So if $H^* BG$ is zero in all but finitely many degrees and thus $\chi(BG)$ is a finite number, we would have $$\chi(BG) = \frac{1}{\chi(G)}.$$  This would only make sense if $\chi(G) = \pm 1$.  However, for example if $G$ is a connected compact Lie group, then $\chi(G) = 0$ and $\chi(BG)$ wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I think this argument also applies to connected compact topological groups, since you can prove $\chi(G)=0$ using Lefschetz fixed-point theorem (as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888519/prove-that-for-a-path-connected-topological-group-g-the-euler-characteristic)), and by extension any topological group with compact components since $\chi$ is additive for disjoint unions. Moreover I think it also applies to an arbitrary Lie group because the identity component is homotopy equivalent to its maximal compact subgroup. Does that sound right?

Comment: Sounds right to me.